# How to get an amount of movement of bluetooth mouse (connecting to Android) by Android application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, mouse

I'm using bluetooth mouse for operating Android device, and I want to get the amount of movement of mouse.
if the cursor goes out of screen, Android-OS Automatically changes cursor-coordinates into inside of screen. So I have problem.

When I using my PC, I move cursor-coordinates into a center of PC screen, and move mouse(by using hand), and (After x - Before x) is the amount of movement. it repeats at every frame.
But the method of moving-cursor is not usable in not-Rooted Android(security problem).

Now, I get the amount of movements by this method. Mouse(connected PC) -> (bluetooth) -> PC -> (UDP) -> smartphone. But this is not speedy(Max about 3000ms latency)...
And, bluetooth mouse is too small to solder(hack)...
By using NDK, AMOTION_getRawX() is just return the coordinates on the screen...

So I want to get the amount of movement of mouse by Android application.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!!

I used "Android Terminal Emulator" app (to start ADB), and ADB command `adb shell getevent -lt /dev/input/event5`.
`event5` maybe change in your device, so check yours use `adb shell getevent -i`

It tells all event log contains `REL_X` and `REL_Y`.(real time)
There are amount of movement of mouse.
If the cursor is edge, no problem.

I converted this hexadecimal String value to int.
`int d = (int)Long.parseLong(hexValue, 16);`